# Is it necessary to commit DVC files from our CI pipelines?

Tags: git, machine-learning, continuous-integration, dvc, mlops

DVC uses git commits to save the experiments and navigate between experiments.

Is it possible to avoid making auto-commits in CI/CD (to save data artifacts after `dvc repro` in CI/CD side).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> will you make it part of CI pipeline

DVC often serves as a part of MLOps infrastructure. There is a popular [blog post about CI/CD for ML](https://martinfowler.com/articles/cd4ml.html) where DVC is used under the hood. [Another example](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/01/remote-training-gitlab-ci-dvc/) but with GitLab CI/CD.

> scenario where you will integrate dvc commit command with CI
>   pipelines?

If you mean `git commit` of DVC files (not `dvc commit`) then yes, you need to commit dvc-files into Git during CI/CD process. Auto-commit is not the best practice.

How to avoid Git commit in CI/CD:

1. After ML model training in CI/CD, save changed dvc-files in external storage (for example GitLab artifact/releases), then get the files to a developer machine and commit there. Users usually write scripts to automate it.
2. Wait for DVC 1.0 release when [run-cache (like build-cache)](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1234) will be implemented. Run-cache makes dvc-files ephemeral and no additional Git commits will be required. Technically, run-cache is an associative storage `repo state --> run results` outside of Git repo (in data remote).

Disclaimer: I'm one of the creators of DVC.

Comment: `Run-cache makes dvc-files ephemeral and no additional Git commits will be required`

@dmitry-petrov wanted a clarification:
- with DVC 1.0 is it not required to commit dvc-files into git?
- Will dvc-files will be tracked in run-cache?
- For a given git-commit How will you map which dvc results to be fetched from cache?
- Will run experiment parameters/code in current git-commit version is enough to fetch appropriate dvc results from cache?
- I still have some doubts around how with DVC 1.0 only changed stages are run, but for now for simplicity say I have only 1 stage in pipeline.

Comment: @B.P.PuneethPai dvc-files will be still here and can be committed/freeze to Git. At the same time, run-cache track "ephemeral" state (but per stage, not per dvc-file). A user can apply ephemeral state to dvc-file (by `dvc repro`) and commit to Git if needed. 
So, you can bring my training results to your machine w/o sharing a commit. Or you can take results from Ci/CD w/o commit.

Comment: @B.P.PuneethPai This is a very good question - people frequently ask... I'd really appreciate if you could modify it and resolve the "opinion-based" issue. To rephrase the question you can ask about Git commit directly.

Comment: Just an update. DVC 1.0 is released - https://dvc.org/blog/dvc-1-0-release
Now you avoid the auto-commits in CI/CD side using the run-cache -  `dvc push --run-cache` and `dvc pull --run-cache`.

Comment: This is great. Have been thinking how to use dvc together with gitlab cicd yml. It'd be great if there is a chapter in the tutorial on this.